# Поиск открытого окна в консоли с использованием цикла

Tags: c#

Не могу сделать проверку открытого окна в цикле.

```
IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4");
while (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) 
{
    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)  // скорее всего это лишнее)
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено"); 
       // Если окно не нашли то возвращаемся к поиску.
    }
    else 
    { 
       Если нашли то делаем что либо:
       Console.WriteLine("окно найдено"); 
    } 
      Console.Read(); 
}
```

А дальше если окно закрыли делаем проверку снова, и так бесконечно.

Comment: Установите hook. Есть hook-процедура, в которую приходит уведомление о создании любого top-окна.

Comment: C хуками работал очень мало, можно подробнее?

Comment: Вариант попроще, можно проверить валидность окна так `IsWindow(ptr)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Как только окна не станет - оно вернёт false

Comment: А как у вас в цикле меняется `ptr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перечитал вопрос внимательнее. Тогда так:

```
while (true) 
{
    IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4");

    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено");
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    else 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("окно найдено");
       do Thread.Sleep(1000); while (WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4") == ptr);
    } 
}
```

или так:

```
IntPtr ptr, old = IntPtr.Zero

while (true) 
{
    ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4");

    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено");
    }
    else if (ptr == old)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("окно уже обработано");
    }
    else 
    {
       Console.WriteLine("окно найдено");
       old = ptr;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

---

Переставь строки в соответствии с номерами (X - удалить).
Строку 3 разделить на 0 и 3 - в 0 объявление переменной, в 3 - присваивание.

```
3 IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4");
1 while (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) 
2 {
4    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)  // скорее всего это лишнее)
X    { 
5       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено"); 
X       // Если окно не нашли то возвращаемся к поиску.
X    }
X    else 
X    { 
7       Если нашли то делаем что либо:
8       Console.WriteLine("окно найдено"); 
X    } 
5      Console.Read(); 
6 }
```

Должно получиться так:

```
IntPtr ptr;

while ((ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "VKMusic4")) == IntPtr.Zero)
{
  Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено"); 
  Console.Read(); 
}

Console.WriteLine("окно найдено");
```

Comment: Если окно открыто то консоль закрывается, если окна нету консоль висит, а вот если окно есть мне нужно какое нибудь действие сделать?! после `if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) break;`

Comment: Может вам нужно поставить **Sleep** что б не вешать систему в цикле, а сообщение не найдено - не выводить? А перед `Console.Read` вам нужно поставить проверку заполнен ли буфер консоли.

Comment: @ArteS, ответ обновлён. Я невнимательно вопрос прочитал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Это уже что-то) Но ведь цикл идёт только если окно не найдено, если нашло, то  если окно будет снова закрыто, то как продолжить цикл поиска окна?

Comment: @ArteS, эм.. бесконечный цикл идёт... бесконечно. И на каждой итерации ищет окно. Что не так с закрытием?

Comment: [Чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49589/)